# PHP foreach change two-dimensional original array values

Tags: php

I need to replace null value to 0 and change original arrays to output.  My code are not work...
Only change the second foreach loop value. how to do it?
I need the output array is... (My null value is not fixed in key)
thank you very much...
my array:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [D1] => 2
                [D2] => 2
                [D3] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [D4] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [D6] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [N1] => 1
                [N2] => 1
                [N3] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [N4] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [N5] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [D1] => 3
                [D2] => 2
                [D3] => 2
                [D4] => 2
                [D5] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [D6] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [T1] => 1
                [T2] => 1
                [T3] => -1
                [T4] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
                [T5] =>   (Expect the null value to change to 0)
            )
    
    )
```

Below is my code:

```
 foreach($myArray as $key=> $value){
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
            if(empty($value[$key2])){
             $value[$key2]="0";
           }
             //print_R($value[$key2]);
}
```

Comment: Change `empty` to `== null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&` which passes variable reference in the foreach loop.
You can try the below codes.

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => &$value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        if($value2 == null) {
         $value[$key2]="0";
        }
    }
}
print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: You have a slight error in second `foreach`, it should be `$key2`. Also note that your condition of `!$value2` overwrites any falsey value, not just `null` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @El_Vanja for correcting me, I had edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($myArray as $key=> $value){
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
            if(empty($value[$key2]) || $value[$key] === null){ //added null checking, you can add more:  $value[$key] == ""
             $value[$key2] = 0; //changed to int (using "0" makes string)
           }
             //print_R($value[$key2]);
}
```